# How to keep the horizontal scrollable and keep the static button on it in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

[image: The given image is in the link]

I don't know to keep the left side to be scrolling and right to be static at one place with out changing its position.

Comment: Can you include sample code that will reproduce the issue and what exactly you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

try to give the left side specific width or try wrap it using expanded

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Use **Row** Widget and wrap the first children in **SingleChildScrollView**. Don't forget to put *scrollDirection* in **SingleChildScrollView**.

Also, you may need to define the width of a second child.